# How to detect reorder of old order in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to detect reorder of old order in woocommerce?
I want to remove any product if customer is reordering any old order, please help.
I know how to remove any product but I am unable to detect that customer is re-ordering any old order.
eg. Suppose user has purchased any order that's have 2 products and when user is trying to purchase same order I want to remove 1 product from the order. I don't want that user remove this product from cart.

Answer (score 0):

After searching a lot and after reading some woocommerce core files I found below solution:

```
add_action("woocommerce_ordered_again", "dbr_remove_all_product_except_the_subscription_func");
function dbr_remove_all_product_except_the_subscription_func()
{
    $cart_items = WC()->cart->get_cart(); /* if needed get cart like this */
    /* code here as per your requirement. */

}
```